# Strategy / RPG source Code Android/Java

Tags: android

I'm looking to study source code from Strategy or RPG games in java.  I was hoping to find more than one source on each genre as to study different approaches.

Does anyone know where I would be able to find any?  I got an account on Safari Books Online, in hope that one of the books on android would cover the genre I was looking for, but they do not have any like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would check out Andor's Trail on the Android Market.  It's an RPG that is free to download and the source code is available here:  http://code.google.com/p/andors-trail/

Good luck!